# gradle dependencies for main and test

Tags: gradle, dependencies

Selenide + Gradle When declaring a dependency like this:

testImplementation group: 'com.codeborne', name: 'selenide', version: '6.6.3' , I can only access Selenid elements and methods in **test/java**. But the page objects are in the **src/main/java** section. How should I write a dependency so that methods can be called both in test and in main? I did this, but it seems to me that it is wrong:
dependencies {

testImplementation group: 'com.codeborne', name: 'selenide', version: '6.6.3'
compileOnly group: 'com.codeborne', name: 'selenide', version: '6.6.3'

}

Answer (score 0):

`testImplentation` means the dependency only has scope for testing. Change it to just `implentation` and it should work.